# node.js module/export system: is it possible to export a module as a function

Tags: javascript, module, node.js

I want to do something like this in Dispatch.js

```
function handle(msg) {
    ....
}
exports = handle;
```

and this in the calling index.js

```
var dispatch = require("./Dispatch);
dispatch("data");
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`exports = handle`

This creates a local variable called `exports`. This is different from overwriting `module.exports`.

`module.exports = handle`

This overwrites the exports variable that lives in module scope, this will then be read by `require`.

In the browser `window["foo"]` and `foo` are the same, however in node `module["foo"]` and `foo` behave subtly different.

The local variable scope context and `module` are not the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Do:

```
function handle(msg) {
    ....
}
module.exports = handle;
```

and it works the way you want.

Comment: or module.exports = function(msg) { }

Answer (score 0):

The problem behind this issue (`exports` vs `module.exports` vs `exports.something`) is best described in this article:

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/getoutbindingsituations

The first version (`exports = handle`) is exactly the problem: the missing binding that is mandatory in javascript:

`exports = handle` means `window.exports = handle` (or whatever node.js has as the global object)

Answer (score 0):

Another way of seeing the problem is thinking about how node could load your module:

`function loadModule(module, exports) {`

inside here comes your module code

`}`

If your code overwrites the `exports` parameter (`exports = handle`), this change is not visible from the outside of this function. And for this overwriting one can use the `module` object.

The problem would not occur if exports would be a variable visible in the scope where the function body is.