# Adding external javascript files on node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a node server and I want to add an external .js file (say `something.js`). I have this code for now:

`var st = require('./js/something');`

Where `something.js` is the JavaScript file inside a `/js/` folder. The server compiles and run, but when I try to use functions defined in `something.js` node tells me they are not defined.

I also tried to run them using like `st.s()` but nothing happens and I have an error saying that the object has no method `s()`.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks,

EDIT:

logging `st` gives `{}` (I obtain it from `console.log(JSON.stringify(st))`. Also doing `console.log(st)` gives `{}` as result.

The content of `something.js` is just a bunch of functions defined like this

```
function s() {
    alert("s");
}

function t() {
    alert("t");
}
```

Comment: Can you paste the something.js code here?

Comment: Use exports: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5939423/node-js-module-export-system-is-it-possible-to-export-a-module-as-a-function

Comment: You don't need to convert it to JSON. Just do `console.dir( st );`...

Comment: Racar can you please be more specific about exports? I didn't get from that question how to use them, or how should I use them in this case.

Comment: in your something.js file, do " module.exports = { st: function() { console.log('test'); } } ".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Node.js uses the [CommonJS](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html) module format. Essentially values that are attached to the `exports` object are available to users of the module. So if you are using a module like this

```
var st = require('./js/something');
st.s();
st.t();
```

Your module has to export those functions. So you need to attach them to the exports object.

```
exports.s = function () {
    console.log("s");
}

exports.t = function () {
    console.log("t");
}
```

Comment: How would you import a script from an external URL (for example, http://javascript-modules.googlecode.com/svn/functionChecker.js)? Using `require("http://javascript-modules.googlecode.com/svn/functionChecker.js");` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Agreed!  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481058/load-and-execute-external-js-file-in-node-js-with-access-to-local-variables