# node.js with dygraphs and canvas.toDataURL()

Tags: javascript, node.js, spidermonkey, dygraphs

Is it possible to include and use external scripts, such as dygraphs and Canvas2Image in node.js?

I have a php script that normaly draws data in dygraphs and then makes dataURL, calls another php script (ajax) that saves the images into a pdf. And I'm looking for a way that this can be done automatically, without a browser, but with cron instead (Ubuntu server). I know, I can replace dygraphs with PHPlot but if there's a way of doing the javascript (dygraphs, jquery and canvas2image) without the browser (on the server) that would be the preferred way.

I found some resources: [external scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8508383/adding-external-javascript-files-on-node-js) and [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801160/can-i-use-jquery-with-node-js)

but I'm really new to node.js and I don't understand, how to use standard javascript([dygraphs](http://dygraphs.com/gallery/#g/per-series) and [canvas2image](http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/), especially with html and getElementById())

I also stumbled across: PECL and spidermonkey - [link](http://devzone.zend.com/1480/using-javascript-in-php-with-pecl-and-spidermonkey/) - is this better for this?