# How do I export a JavaScript class in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

In its simplest form, here is the issue where a class will not be correctly returned exported if it is a class.

app.js

```
var Users = require('./users.js');
Users.find('test');
```

users.js

```
var Users = function() {
  function Users() {
    console.log('Users Initiated');
  }

  Users.prototype.find = function(username) {
    console.log(username);
  };

  return Users;

}

module.exports = Users;
```

The error I receive in the console

```
/Users/me/nodejsClassExport/app.js:2
Users.find('test');
      ^
TypeError: Object function () {
  function Users() {
    console.log('Users Initiated');
  }

  Users.prototype.find = function(username) {
    console.log(username);
  };

  return Users;

} has no method 'find'
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/me/nodejsClassExport/app.js:2:7)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3
```

How do I export it correctly so it can be used without crashing?

Comment: You haven't posted enough code for anybody to see what's wrong.

Comment: possible duplicate of [node.js module/export system: is it possible to export a module as a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5939423/node-js-module-export-system-is-it-possible-to-export-a-module-as-a-function)

Comment: Your latest update makes it clear that Pointy's answer is correct. There is no `User.find` function, which is why you can't call it. There is a `find` function that will exist on **instances** created via `new User`, which is a completely different thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're "Users" object is a function, a constructor apparently. You can't get to methods of a constructor's prototype from the constructor directly like that. You can however create an *instance* and access the prototypes that way.

```
var u = new Users();
u.find(whatever);
```

*edit* — now, back in the module, you've got two "Users" symbols. One is that outer function, and the other is that "Users" function declared inside it. However, what you export is the outer one, and it doesn't have a "find" method on its prototype. You can solve this problem by calling the outer "Users" function to get to the proper one. That can be done either in the module or in the client context, though I suspect you probably want it in the module:

```
module.exports = Users();
```

Comment: I just can't seem to get this working. Please see this gist http://gist.github.com/krazyjakee/bc53d93eeac042865bae

Comment: @JakeCattrall ok I'll extend the answer.

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_exports):

> The `module.exports` object is created by the Module system. Sometimes this is not acceptable; many want their module to be an instance of some class. To do this assign the desired export object to `module.exports`. Note that assigning the desired object to `exports` will simply rebind the local `exports` variable, which is probably not what you want to do.

So replace

```
exports = Users;
```

with

```
module.exports = Users;
```

Comment: @JakeCattrall: There's not much more code in the question, it's still really unclear. (For instance: Are you really adding a `find` function as a property on your `User` function? Rather than on its `prototype` property, where it will show up on *instances* [not the function itself]?) Create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @JakeCattrall: It does indeed. It means that replacing `exports =` with `module.exports =` (above) was necessary, **and** that once we fixed that problem, Pointy's answer deals with the next problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with this line:

```
this.users = nStore["new"]('data/users.db');
```

It is either not saving a new object to `this.users` or it falling victim to an asynchronous race condition, as it is complaining about how `this.users.find()` does not exist.

Likely, it is because that function for `nStore` takes a callback, so you'll have to consider that with the rest of your code.

```
this.users = nStore.new('data/users.db', function () {
  console.log('Users Initiated');
  // now it is safe to use the methods in 'this.users'
});
```

Comment: The OP isn't calling `find` on `this.users`, he's calling it on `User`.